# Перевод сайта ВП

Tags: wordpress, перевод

Подскажите куда копать. Может есть возможность определенные фразы в ворд прессе через функшен пхп перевести.В общем проблема в том что никак не могу придумать как перевести некоторые фразы на сайте ворд пресс. Например день или Смотрите больше от компании

Вот например проблемная [страница](https://test.auto-arenda.kiev.ua/en/car/mercedes-benz-sprinter-new-2/)

Использую Loco Translate и
Polylang

Answer (score 1):

Они похоже не добавлены в файл перевода. Поэтому нужно править только через код...

1. Ищите необходимую фразу по всему проекту - переводите.
2. Придется доработать перевод самому. Можно почитать тут - https://ru.wplang.org/wordpress-perevod-temy-plaginy/

Comment: ну  Смотрите больше от компании идет через плагин  Contextual Related Posts. А вот как добавить перевод для en

Comment: спасибо сейчас почитаю

Answer (score 0):

> Может есть возможность определенные фразы в ворд прессе через функшен пхп перевести

Перевод строк в ВП осуществляется с пом. [gettext](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext).

> Подскажите куда копать.

https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/

Вкратце:

1. Код строк должен быть подготовлен доя перевода. Т.е. оформлен в функции начинающихся с `_` (см по ссылке). Оригинальный язык - анг и никакой другой.
2. Должен быть создан лангпак (файлы *.mo и *.po) который должен
   2.1 иметь имена файлов в соответствии с текстовым доменом (см по ссылке) и указателем языка
   2.2 расположен в системном каталоге (`/wp-content/languages/themes/` для тем, `/wp-content/languages/plugins/` для плагинов), либо каталоге, указанным в 
   функции [load_plugin_textdomain](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_plugin_textdomain)